# WinForm Design Error: Why am I seeing this page?

Tags: winforms, designer

```
Object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Jud.Itd.Cmis.BusinessObjects.AddressType]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[Jud.Itd.Cmis.BusinessObjects.AddressType]'.
```

Closing Visual Studio and reopening and recompiling all fixes it, so I would say that this is clearly a bug and a huge nuisance.

The question is, is there a work around other than restarting VS or living without the Designer? Cleaning the app and recompiling all doesn't do it.

```
Instances of this error (1)  

1.   Hide Call Stack 

at System.RuntimeType.CheckValue(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
at System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo.InternalSetValue(Object obj, Object value, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, Boolean doVisibilityCheck, Boolean doCheckConsistency)
at System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo.InternalSetValue(Object obj, Object value, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, Boolean doVisibilityCheck)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationFieldInfo.InternalSetValue(Object obj, Object value, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, Boolean requiresAccessCheck, Boolean isBinderDefault)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.SerializationSetValue(MemberInfo fi, Object target, Object value)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.CompleteObject(ObjectHolder holder, Boolean bObjectFullyComplete)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoNewlyRegisteredObjectFixups(ObjectHolder holder)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.RegisterObject(Object obj, Int64 objectID, SerializationInfo info, Int64 idOfContainingObj, MemberInfo member, Int32[] arrayIndex)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.RegisterObject(Object obj, ParseRecord pr, ParseRecord objectPr, Boolean bIsString)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.ParseObjectEnd(ParseRecord pr)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Parse(ParseRecord pr)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream)
at System.Resources.ResXDataNode.GenerateObjectFromDataNodeInfo(DataNodeInfo dataNodeInfo, ITypeResolutionService typeResolver)
at System.Resources.ResXDataNode.GetValue(ITypeResolutionService typeResolver)
at System.Resources.ResXResourceReader.ParseDataNode(XmlTextReader reader, Boolean isMetaData)
at System.Resources.ResXResourceReader.ParseXml(XmlTextReader reader)  

Help with this error  

MSDN Help   


Forum posts about this error  

Search the MSDN Forums for posts related to this error
```

Comment: You didn't post *nearly* enough code for anyone to diagnose or reproduce your problem. The error message makes things pretty obvious, it seems.

Comment: Can you paste the code in the designer where it fails, it might be pointing where in this **List** is being declared or are you using any UserControl ?

Comment: @Cody: Why is the compiler even attempting to convert an object of type X to an object that is alreay of type X? It's certainly not clear to me.

Comment: No idea. As I said before, I'd have to see your code to tell you why.

Comment: @ChadD Have you even read my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I might have an answer. I just encountered the same error and I found out that this is produced if there are some errors in a `Form` constructor or the `Form_Load()` method. I tried to comment out code in these methods and when it didn't helped I realized that there must be en error in some component.

And it was. If you use some custom component and it have some properties set to null even after a constructor of this component is called it could cause this rendering error.

You can find these properties in your `Form.resx` file. They will have value in the `Value` column set to `(Nothing/null)`.

What helped me was to delete these bad lines there and mark my properties with the following attributes.

```
[Browsable(false), DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
```

Answer (score -1):

The WinForm Designer has a bug. In fact, this bug rates as the most complained about bug in WinForm development. Live with it.

Comment: Can you give us some more information? What's the bug? What causes it? I've never seen anyone complain about this, nor have I personally experienced it in my extensive usage of the designer. Do you have a link to a bug report on Microsoft Connect? If not, I encourage you to file one, if you have a set of repro steps. (They get closed pretty quickly as "no repro" without them.)